# SQL2000 Read Only View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've checked BOL and I don't see what I'm looking for.  I know that Oracle has a "WITH READ ONLY" option when creating a view.  I don't see this option in SQL2000.  Do I need to add an INSTEADOF trigger to accomplish this?  In short, I don't want users of the view to be able to update the data.

Thanks
ST

Answer (score 1):

two options, don't give users insert, delete or update permissions to the view

```
deny update, insert, delete on ViewName to [user name(s) here]
```

or create a the view on a read only filegroup (this means that nobody can insert or update or delete)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that.  I knew of those but neither are possible.  I'll create "instead of " triggers which throw errors.

Thanks
ST